# Remove duplicate objects in JSON and form an array

Tags: javascript, json

Need to iterate over the below JSON object and form a result json which has the unique data. Result will be basically consist of the list of questions and their choices. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance..!!

```
    var data = [
  {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the best footballer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Messi",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
  },
  {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the best footballer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Ronaldo",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
  },
  {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the best footballer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Ibrahimovic",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
  },
  {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the top goal scorer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Messi",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
  },
  {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the top goal scorer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Ronaldo",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
  },
  {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the top goal scorer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Lewandoski",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
  }
];
```

JSON to populate

```
{
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "category": "sports",
    "createdUserId": "1",
    "questionList": [
        {
            "question": "Who is the best footballer?",
            "questionType": "text",
            "choices": [
                "Messi",
                "Ronaldo",
                "Ibrahimovic"
            ]
        },
        {
            "question": "Who is the top goal scorer?",
            "questionType": "text",
            "choices": [
                "Messi",
                "Ronaldo",
                "Lewandoski"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, I use an **object** `qObj` so that the question can be located, otherwise we have to traverse the **array** to find whether the question exists.

```js
"use strict";

var data = [{
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the best footballer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Messi",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
}, {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the best footballer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Ronaldo",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
}, {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the best footballer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Ibrahimovic",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
}, {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the top goal scorer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Messi",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
}, {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the top goal scorer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Ronaldo",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
}, {
    "category": "sports",
    "question": "Who is the top goal scorer?",
    "questionType": "text",
    "choices": "Lewandoski",
    "name": "Best Footballer",
    "createdUserId": 1
}];

var pop = {
    name: "Best Footballer",
    category: "sports",
    createdUserId: "1",
    questionList: []
};
var qObj = {};

data.forEach(function(entry) {

    if (typeof qObj[entry.question] == "undefined") {
        qObj[entry.question] = [];
    }

    qObj[entry.question].push(entry.choices);

});

for (var q in qObj) {
    if (qObj.hasOwnProperty(q)) {
        pop.questionList.push({
            question: q,
            questionType: "text",
            choices: qObj[q]
        });
    }
}

console.log(pop); // JavaScript Object
console.log(JSON.stringify(pop)); // json
```

Comment: Thank you so much.!! Its perfect.!!